# Is there something like .take for varchar?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a table that has addresses in it and I need to retrieve at least 13 of them in order after they are sorted by street name and street number.  Both fields are stored as nvarchar so .take will not work as from my understanding that only works with int.    The problem is the ID field is sorted by what is called a BRT Number which only correlates with street name / street number 80% of the time due to reassessments.

Any ideas?

Current code looks like this.

```
private void textBox5_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataClasses3DataContext db = new DataClasses3DataContext();

            int matchedAdd = (from c in db.GetTable<prop>()
                              where c.LOC.Contains(textBox1.Text) && c.Direction.Contains(textBox2.Text) && c.LOC.Contains(textBox4.Text) && c.LOC.Contains(textBox5.Text)
                              select c.ID).Single();



            var before = (from c in db.GetTable<prop>()
                          where c.ID <= matchedAdd
                          orderby c.ID
                          orderby c.ID descending
                          select c).Take(7);

            var after = (from c in db.GetTable<prop>()
                         where c.ID > matchedAdd
                         orderby c.ID
                         select c).Take(6);


            var endResult = before.Union(after);

            dgvBRT.DataSource = endResult.OrderByDescending(i => i.streetNum);

        }
```

Comment: Note: using two `orderby` clauses is almost never a good idea - and using two for the same property is a *really* bad idea.

Comment: Oops I didn't realize that was there.  I was trying something else and forgot to comment that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both fields are stored as nvarchar so .take will not work as from my understanding that only works with int.

Nope, it should be absolutely fine, although your `before` query is a bit odd due to having `orderby` twice. (Ditch the first one.)

The *argument* for `Take` has to be an `int` to say how many items you want to take, but the items you're fetching can be anything.

Comment: Ah okay that is good to know!  Guess its back to querying!  I must have read the MSDN library on .take incorrectly. Thanks.